# Check file extension

Tags: powershell, file-extension

I am using the following PowerShell code and I need to check its extension in an if condition

```powershell
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $extn = $line.Split("{.}")[1]
    if ($extn -eq "xml" )
    {
    }
}
```

Is there a straightforward way to check string extensions in PowerShell script in case of strings?

Answer (score 28):

You can simply use the [`GetExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx) function from `System.IO.Path`:

```powershell
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $extn = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($line)
    if ($extn -eq ".xml" )
    {
    }
}
```

Demo:

```powershell
PS > [IO.Path]::GetExtension('c:\dir\file.xml')
.xml   
PS > [IO.Path]::GetExtension('c:\dir\file.xml') -eq '.xml'
True
PS > [IO.Path]::GetExtension('Test1.xml') # Also works with just file names
.xml    
PS > [IO.Path]::GetExtension('Test1.xml') -eq '.xml'
True    
PS >
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `-Like` operator:

```
if ($line -Like "*.xml")
{
    ...
}
```

See [PowerShell Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators).