# size of files based on particular extensions

Tags: powershell, fileserver

I am trying to find all files in a specific drive that are accessed before 40 days, find their file type and specificy size of files based on extension. 
I have 40000 files in 126 folders, and total of 51 different extensions (file types), now that i want to find what type of file occupy who much space.

With this I got file count based on extension:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path X:\ -Recurse |where{-not $_.PSIsContainer} | group Extension -NoElement
```

With this I got number of unique extensions:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path X:\ -Recurse | Select-Object -Property Extension -Unique

Get-ChildItem -Path X:\ -Recurse |where{-not $_.PSIsContainer} | group Extension -NoElement

Get-ChildItem -Path X:\ -Recurse | Select-Object -Property Extension -Unique
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Which part of the code does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this.

```
# directory path
$directory = "C:\Program Files"

# date -40 days
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-40)

# files which are accessed before 40 days
$files = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -File:$true | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date}

# sort files by extension, size
$files | Sort-Object Extension,Length | Select-Object Name,@{label = 'Length'; e = {"{0:N3} KB" -f ($_.Length / 1KB)}} | ft -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Comment: Well, I suppose we are near to it, but I do not want the exact file names. 
I just want to show the extensions and thier size for example. JPEG - 2000 files 4 GB
.DOC - 1086 files - 4 GB like wise.

Comment: I am able to get the total extensions and total size for them.
but, unable to get the size for each extension type.

Comment: try this: [Check File Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787364/check-file-extension)

Answer (score 0):

I'll hope it is not so bad. :)

```
# directory path
$directory = "X:\"

# date -40 days
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-40)

# files which are accessed before 40 days
$files = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -File:$true | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date} 

# file extensions
$fileExtensions = $files | Select-Object -Property Extension -Unique


    foreach ($ext in $fileExtensions){

        [int]$fileSize = $null

        foreach ($file in $files) {

            if ($file.Extension -like $ext.Extension) {

                [int]$fileSize += $file.Length / 1KB
            }
        }

        Write-Host "Extension:" $ext.Extension " - Size: "$fileSize "KB"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, I'm not sure how to format it in a table:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -File:$true | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date} 

foreach($file in $files){
[IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)
$file.length
}
```